# MySQL not showing duplicate column names in separate tables using INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have a database with 22 tables most tables have a few column fields with identical names. When I use INNER JOIN on the tables with the duplicate column names it will ignore them in the last table. Right now I am only joining 3 tables

```
SELECT * FROM company C 
INNER JOIN typeofdealer PI ON C.CompanyID = PI.CompanyID 
INNER JOIN typeofservices TS ON PI.CompanyID = TS.CompanyID
```

So in this example `typeofdealer` and `typeofservices` both contain column names `Other` and `OtherText` When I get this query back I only see one `Other` and one `OtherText`.

I just discovered as I was writing this that if I do the query in "phpmyadmin" that I get it back exactly as intended. I am doing this query using prepared statements in php and outputting the results using:

```
echo "<PRE>";
print_r($results);
echo "</PRE>";
```

I believe the problem is that php arrays cannot contain duplicate fields so is there a way to circumvent the issue I am having?

Comment: Did you check that the result does not have additional columns like Other_1, usually if the result has identical column names, it would try to use aliases

Comment: using `var_dump` does not list any aliases it basically removes the matching field names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround you can do for this is to use an alias `AS` to make a distinction between columns with the same names. Something like:

```
SELECT PI.Other AS Other1, PI.OtherText AS OtherText2, TS.Other AS Other2, TS.OtherText AS OtherText2 FROM company C 
INNER JOIN typeofdealer PI ON C.CompanyID = PI.CompanyID 
INNER JOIN typeofservices TS ON PI.CompanyID = TS.CompanyID
```

Actually it will work the same way if you omit the AS keyword say `SELECT PI.Other Other1, PI.OtherText OtherText2`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, as you rightfully suggested, that PHP won't allow multiple entries into an array with the same key name.

The simplest way around this, is to alias the fields in the column selection section of the query, like so:

```
SELECT *, typeofservices.Other as ServicesOther, typeofservices.OtherText as ServicesOtherText FROM company C 
INNER JOIN typeofdealer PI ON C.CompanyID = PI.CompanyID 
INNER JOIN typeofservices TS ON PI.CompanyID = TS.CompanyID
```

It's not pretty but it's simple.

Comment: Do you know of an SQL query to find duplicate column names?